# Weird Laplace Equation.

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm stuck with this PDE problem.

> Let $R>0$ and let $u:\overline{B(0,R)}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuos function such that:
>   $$\left\{\begin{matrix} \Delta u +u= u^3 & \text{ in } B(0,R)\\ u = 0 & \text{ on } \partial B(0,R)\end{matrix}\right.$$
>   Prove that $|u(x)|\leq 1$ for all $x\in B(0,R)$.

I've managed to prove that:
$$\int_{B(0,R)} (u^4-u^2) \leq 0$$
But it doesn't seem to be useful. (It can be seen by multiplying the equation by $u$ and then integrating using Green's identity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe
\begin{align}
-\int_{B(0, R)} (2k-1) u^{2k-2}|\nabla u|^2=\int_{B(0, R)} u^{2k-1}\Delta u \ dx = \int_{B(0, R)} u^{2k-1}(u^3-u)\ dx \leq 0
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\int_{B(0, R)} u^{2(k+1)}\ dx \leq \int_{B(0, R)} u^{2k}\ dx \leq \ldots \leq \int_{B(0, R)} u^2\ dx
\end{align}
for all $k\geq 1$.
In particular, it follows
\begin{align}
\| u\|_{L^{2(k+1)}(B(0, R))} \leq \| u\|_{L^2(B(0, R))}^{\frac{1}{k+1}}\rightarrow 1
\end{align} 
as $k \rightarrow \infty$. Moreover, since
\begin{align}
\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\|u\|_{L^{2(k+1)}(B(0, R))} = \| u\|_{L^\infty(B(0, R))}
\end{align}
then it follows
\begin{align}
\| u\|_{L^\infty(B(0, R))}\leq1.
\end{align}

Comment: Brilliant. I was just wondering why would someone insist (as in the case of my professor) that it was useful to pay attention to the fact that the domain of the problem was "a ball".

Comment: You need the finite measure of the ball. Otherwise the limit of the $L^p$ norms will not be $L^\infty$.

Comment: Of course. But your solution works not only for a ball but for any bounded connected open set.
Edit: One may even think of using some kind of "Green's Formula" with the idea: "my domain is a ball".

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use $L^p$ estimate. Let $s^+$ define the positive part of $s$, namely if $s\le0$, then $s^+=0$ and if $s>0$, then $s^+=s$. Noting that $(u^2-1)|_{\partial B(0,R)}=0$, by Green's formula, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{B(0,R)}|\nabla(u^2-1)^+|^2dx&=&\int_{B(0,R)}\nabla(u^2-1)\nabla(u^2-1)^+dx \\
&=&-\int_{B(0,R)}(u^2-1)^+\Delta(u^2-1)dx \\
&=&-\int_{B(0,R)}(u^2-1)^+(2|\nabla u|^2+2u\Delta u)dx\\
&=&-2\int_{B(0,R)}(u^2-1)^+|\nabla u|^2dx-\int_{B(0,R)}(u^2-1)^+u\Delta udx\\
&=&-2\int_{B(0,R)}(u^2-1)^+|\nabla u|^2dx-\int_{B(0,R)}(u^2-1)^+u(u^3-u)dx\\
&=&-2\int_{B(0,R)}(u^2-1)^+|\nabla u|^2dx+\int_{B(0,R)}(u^2-1)^+u^2(1-u^2)dx\\
&\le&0
\end{eqnarray}
So $(u^2-1)^+=0$ or $|u|\le1$.